# I have a folder for Guest Additions - does that mean it's installed?

Tags: guest-additions

I am running Ubuntu as host and Windows 10 as a VM. I tried installing guest additions but I am not sure it was successful. I have a folder called guest additions on my Windows 10 (guest VM). Do I need to run this setup file to mount it?

From the Windows 10 guest VM, under CD DRIVE (D:) I see `CCCOMA_X64FRE_EN-US_DV9`. No idea what this is so maybe it's the guest additions file?

Devices:

[image: add devices?]

I'm following [this article](https://www.linuxbabe.com/virtualbox/how-to-increase-virtualbox-disk-size-for-dynamically-allocated-disks)  and I was able to increase my disk size but now I need to do the last step:

> To use this unallocated space, first disable swap partition. Right click on the linux-swap partition and select swapoff.

But.. I think I need to create a partition as I currently don't have that view. It says I'll erase all data if I create one.. what do I do?! Thanks so much in advance...

Partition:

[image: ok to create partition?]

Comment: You're only allowed to ask one question per question. But... 1) no, 2) I don't see SATA.vdi, 3) leave it alone, 4) yes. You're making this all too complicated.

Comment: Thank you!! Guest Additions are installed.  You should see 'Windows 10 VM.vdi' in image 3 (link only, not embedded because I can't do that yet). I think this is the installer file that I can unmount now. I'll research why I have almost used all of my disk space already and will post a new question if necessary. Thanks again.

Comment: No, the "Windows 10 VM.vdi" is your VM system disk. The "Win 10_1903*" is the installer .iso file that you've got mounted in the CD drive, and should be ejected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The folder that you see is probably the Guest Additions CD image that is mounted on the CD drive D:. This contains the Guest Additions installer files.

[image]

To assure that the Guest Additions have been installed, double-click on this folder and locate the installer .exe files. They are **VboxWindowsAdditions-amd64.exe** (for 64-bit installations) or **VboxWindowAdditions-x86.exe** (for 32-bit installations). Double-click on that and follow the instructions. When you're done, unmount the CD drive D:.

**Update #1:**

The image that you just posted is very confusing, but it looks like the CD Drive D: contains the Windows 10 Installer .iso image. Eject that. Go to the `Devices` menu, and select "Insert Guest Additions CD Image", and proceed as above.

**Update #2:**

If the `Devices` menu won't mount the Guest Additions CD image, you can manually find it in `/usr/share/virtualbox/VBoxGuestAdditions.iso`.

Regarding resizing the disk... if this is a fresh VM, and you don't have any files saved yet, it's just easier to delete the VM and start over, this time specifying the desired disk size. The default is probably 8G, and you'll probably want at least 20-40G.

Comment: thank you very much for the quick reply!  I removed that image and tried to insert the guest additions CD image, but I must not have that installed properly for when I try to add one it just keeps spinning... I've looked at other articles and can't figure out where I went wrong, for I do have a folder in my vm, (windows 10) under the start button that says Oracle VM VirtualBox Guest Additions..                        ANOTHER question I have is about the disk space size.. I updated my original post if you have any advice on that as well it'd be really helpful.

Comment: @rbj Please see Update #2 in my answer.